# Edit maven's settings.xml from Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, settings

In Netbeans, maven's `settings.xml` file is part of every project and can easily be edited from each project:

[image]

Is there something similar in Intellij or do I need to manually open the file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not visible by default.

Right Click on POM --> Maven --> Open Settings.xml

[image]